# force nhibernate to save unchanged object (mark it as dirty)

Tags: nhibernate, save

I need to save a unchanged object via nhibernate to get a database trigger fired.

So how can I tell nhibernate that this object is dirty even if no property has changed?

Answer (score 4):

There are NHibernate extension points, exactly for this scenario. In this case, we can append custom `EventListener` or introduce an `IInterceptor`.

Check this question [How to make NHibernate considered property to always be dirty when using dynamic update or insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453591/) for a solution [(answer based on IInterceptor)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13458713/1679310)

See the NHibernate documenation [12. Interceptors and events](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#events)

Comment: The problem with interceptor (finddirty) is that I only have the entity/object itself to decide if non-dirty save is needed or not. But in my scenario there is'nt anything at object scope that I can use for this. so i need to introduce a extra property for this. But I don't want that objects itself know something abouth non-dirty save. This would be the same problem with events to.

Answer (score 4):

So in respect to my comment to Radims answer I did the following:

I changed one entry of the loadedstate array of the entity so nhibernate will see it as changed on next save.

I know that this is a bit of a workaround but for me it works so far.

```
EntityEntry entry = sessImpl.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(dbo);
entry.LoadedState[x] = y;
```