# MVC3 NHibernate, SQL audit

Tags: nhibernate, orm, auditing

I have some misunderstandings about the implementation of an **SQL audit module**, using as ORM **Fluent NHibernate**. So here is the situation:

We are talking about a Client-Server application build on MVC3 framework.
Suppose there we have a method which renders the **grid**:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowGrid()
{
   var gridModel = _gridService.GetAllRecords();
   return View(gridModel);
}
```

Now when somebody executes a DB Inser/Update/Delete command, I want that every client which views that grid to see that there are some changes inside.

I have 3 ideas:

1) To write a script that makes a **refresh** by calling the database, each **X** seconds. Making a full Select even if there are no changes yet. ***Worst decision***

2) To create some sort of trigger, which updates a custom audit table, and then to check if there is some new data, by comparing some Object State/ LastUpdate fields. ***Better***

3) To use some other tools (no have ideea what tools), that will offer some solutions.

If somebody have some information, maybe there already exists a solution please share. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Using NHibernate, the easiest way:

[NHibernate Interceptor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17530/Sample-NHibernate-IInterceptor-implementation)

If you need implement something more complex you can mix it with event listeners:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164655/nhibernate-auditing-with-events-on-update)

Or use:

[NHibernate.Envers](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers)