# Persisting DateTime when saving/updating entities in fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, timestamp, fluent

I'm trying to persist the datetime of creation and update of entites (not relevent to versioning and concurrency) using fluent nhibernate.

To achieve this using nhibernate I would write this mapping tag:

```
<timestamp name="Timestamp" access="property" unsaved-value="null" />
```

How can I make fluent nhiberbate generate that mapping tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean map a `DateTime` property as this:

```
<property name="Timestamp" type="Timestamp"/>
```

This is the equivalent in **Fluent NHibernate**:

```
Map(x => x.Timestamp).CustomType<TimestampType>();
```

Comment: I am trying to generate the values for the column automatically. When I map the column as you suggested, the value inserted into the DB is null

Comment: That is not posible, here are some alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17140292/1486443 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18919702/1486443

Comment: How come this isn't possible? This is a trivial feature. Anyway, I think I favor using interceptors over triggers. I'll submit a request for this feature at github